# Regex in Django query set

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to write a Django query that will filter by a particular regex pattern.

I want to filter by a code that pulls out any cases where there's any non-digit character followed by a number, followed by a non-digit character (a white space is fine).

Just say some codes are `AJDP8EP, jsif28EP, EROE88, oskdpoeks8`.

So I want my results to return: `AJDP8EP, oskdpoeks8`.

This is my query, but it's not recognizing things properly. Number is a variable.

```
results = Book.objects.filter(author__contains = firstname,type = "Fiction").filter(code__regex = r'^(\D+)(number)(\D+)')
```

Comment: How does `oskdpoeks8` match your pattern? Its missing a space or a numeral after the `8`.

Comment: Also, what does your filter return?

Comment: my pattern is non numerical digit followed by numerical digit followed by non numerical digit or white space

Comment: Just an empty list is returned. But there are definitely records that match this code.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a variable inside your quoted regex expression. Try concatenating strings like:

`r"^(\D+)(" + str(number) + ")(\D+)"`

This converts your `number` variable to a string in case it is not already.

Also, as indicated in one of the comments to your question, `oskdpoeks8` will not match your pattern. If you want to catch cases where `number` may come at the end of the code, one solution would be:

`r"^(\D+)(" + str(number) + ")(\D*)"`

Note the replacement of the `+` with an `*` to catch that case of zero occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

With python 3+ and [newer versions on django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#regex) you can make use of f-strings to pass variables to regex and use them in queries. For example:

```
Car.objects.filter(
    car_code__regex=rf'^{settings.SOME_SETTING}0*(\d+)$'
)
```

For the OP's case:

```
results = Book.objects.filter(author__contains = firstname,type = "Fiction").filter(code__regex = rf'^(\D+){number}(\D+)')
```